# rank items in list of string in dart

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart, search, ranking

Let's consider a list:

```
List<String> recipeNamesList = [
  'Burger',
  'French Fries',
  'Pizza',
  'Bengali Lamb Curry',
  'Chingri Malai Curry',
]
```

If the user searches `Bengali Lamb Fries` I need to return `Bengali lamb curry` and `French Fries`.

`Benagli Lamb Curry` will have the highest rank since it has 2 words matching and `French Fries` has only one word that matches.

So the returned list will be something like this:

```
List<String> result = [
  'Bengali Lamb Curry',
  'French Fries'
]
```

My current code:

```
  Future<List<String>> getSuggestions(String search) async {
    List<String> results = [];
    List<String> searchSplit =
        search.toLowerCase().split(" "); // split the search query

    for (int i = 0; i < searchSplit.length; i++) {
      // iterate over search query
      for (int j = 0; j < recipeNamesList.length; j++) {
        // iterate over the recipe names list
        List<String> recipeNamesListSplit =
            recipeNamesList[j].split(" "); // split the recipe names
        for (int k = 0; k < recipeNamesListSplit.length; k++) {
          // iterate over the list of splitted name
          if (recipeNamesListSplit[k]
              .toLowerCase()
              .startsWith(searchSplit[i])) {
            // convert to lower case and check if the query is present in splitted name
            results
                .add(recipeNamesList[j]); // if contains == true add to results
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Avoid repeated values
    results = results.toSet().toList();
    return results;
  }
```

It's a completely ad-hoc that only matches if the query word is present in the `recipeNamesList`. And if so adds them to the `results` list. It does not rank which recipe has the most matched words from the search query.

How am I supposed to rank? Is it possible with my current code with modifications? Or do I need to completely change my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your method as

```
Future<List<String>> getSuggestions(String search) async {
  List<String> result = [];
  recipeNamesList.forEach((word){
    
    int value = getMatching(search,word);
    if(value > 0){
      if(result.isNotEmpty){
        if(getMatching(search,result[0]) > value){
          //only insert the maximum matched value at starting. it is some type of sorting
          result.add(word);
        }else{
          result.insert(0,word);
        }
      }else{
        result.add(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

A basic function to count the exact matched words

```
int getMatching(String input, String word){
   List<String> inn = input.split(' ');
   List<String> words = word.split(' ');
   int temp = 0;
   inn.forEach((inWord){
     if(words.contains(inWord)){
       temp++;
     }
   });
   
   return temp;
 }
```

**Output** with the input `getSuggestions('Bengali Lamb Fries')`

[image]